# How can I have dynamically changing labels in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my iOS app, a tip calculator, you can enter a total for the bill, then press a button, and have three different tips calculated for you. Since I'm using a number keyboard, (with no return or enter key) how can I have my three tip labels change when I am inputting a value into the text field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UITextViewDelegate's

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

method to update the labels.